# how to write one if statement instead of three

Tags: c

I need to use one if statements in the code instead of using 3, does anyone have any idea how i should do that?
My code:

```js
#include < stdio.h >

  int main() {
    int year;

    printf("Enter a year: ");
    scanf("%d", & year);

    if (year % 4 == 0) {
      if (year % 100 == 0) {
        if (year % 400 == 0)
          printf("%d is a leap year.", year);
        else
          printf("%d is not a leap year.", year);
      } else
        printf("%d is a leap year.", year);
    } else
      printf("%d is not a leap year.", year);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Have you hear about the logical operator AND and OR? Using the `&&` and `||` operators respectively. your book, class, or tutorial should have brought them up.

Comment: `if ((year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || year%400==0){//leap year}`

Comment: Here, I Googled it for you.

Answer (score -2):

Yes we can do that using one if statement.

```
if((year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || year%400==0)
{
printf("%d is a leap year.", year);
}
else
{
 printf("%d is not a leap year.", year);
}
```

Comment: This condition is equvalent to `year%400 == 0`, which is not right.

Comment: I have given answer for the above question not for leap year.